# Docker-Compose Persistent Data Trouble

Tags: macos, docker, mariadb, docker-compose

I'm having trouble in configuring persistent data with `Mariadb`.
I'm using `docker-compose`, with each service in a single container (`Nginx`, `PHP-FPM` and `Mariadb`).
Everything is working, except `Mariadb` doesn't store data. Every time I restart the container, I lose all the data. Then I found out that I can use another container just to keep data, and it doesn't even have to be running.

So I'm using, in `Mariadb` container `volume_from` content container. But when I do that, when I try to map the volume `/var/lib/mysql`, the Container `MariaDb` doesn't start.

**Error**

> 2015-12-29 12:16:40 7f2f02e4a780
>   InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
>   InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
>   InnoDB: the directory.

The error refers to a problem about volume permissions, but I've tried to set permissions through `Dockerfile` in both containers, and the problem persists. I'm a bit lost. I'm using OSX, so I believe this is an OSX problem. Can anyone help me on this?

This is my code:

**My Docker Compose**

```
content:
  build: containers/content
  container_name: content
  hostname: content
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql
mariadb:
  build: containers/mariadb
  container_name: mariadb
  hostname: mariadb
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  volumes_from:
    - content
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mariadb
    - TERM=xterm
    - PORT=3306
```

**MariaDB Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  mariadb-server

EXPOSE 3306
```

**Content Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:jessie

VOLUME /var/lib/mysql

CMD ["true"]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way i do it is that I use busybox for all data stored and shared with mariadb. Then use `--volumes-from` in mariadb to link that directories. Please have a look into my simpified `compose.yml` file.

```
db-data:
  container_name: db-data
  image: busybox:latest
  volumes:
    - /data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql

db:
  container_name: db
  image: million12/mariadb
  restart: always
  volumes_from:
    - db-data
  environment:
    - MARIADB_USER=admin
    - MARIADB_PASS=my_pass
```

Now all database files are accessible on host os too and there shouldn't be any permissions issues.

Update for docker-compose 2.0

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  database:

services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: million12/mariadb
    restart: always
    volumes_from:
       - database
     environment:
       - MARIADB_USER=admin
       - MARIADB_PASS=my_pass
```

You can see where docker is storing that volume on your hard drive by running command:
`docker volume inspect docker_database`

```
[
{
    "Name": "docker_database",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/docker_database/_data",
    "Labels": null,
    "Scope": "local"
}
```

]

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.

Comment: It worked. I was creating my own dockerfile to Mariadb (it's not wrong, but harder), and I was using docker rm every time I was closing Docker. But now, with that image that doesn't happen. The problem was not exactly solved, but this is a good solution also.

Comment: This article suggests that you should use the same image for the db and data-volume containers: http://container42.com/2014/11/18/data-only-container-madness/

Comment: What's the advantage of this approach versus having the data in the same container as the db?

Comment: thanks. this might be a handy command to know, to see what the volume name is, to inspect the volume: docker volume ls

Comment: This still worked for me in 2022 with mysql-server:8.0 and the cool thing is you can leave the my.cnf alone! (unlike the suggestions provided with the mysql docker image.)  Now on to step 2, which is to get phpmyadmin running in another container in the stack.