# Docker-Compose persistent data MySQL

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I can't seem to get MySQL data to persist if I run `$ docker-compose down` with the following `.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  # other services

  data:
    container_name: flask_data
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql
    command: "true"

  mysql:
    container_name: flask_mysql
    restart: always
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'test_pass' # TODO: Change this
      MYSQL_USER: 'test'
      MYSQL_PASS: 'pass'
    volumes_from:
      - data
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

My understanding is that in my `data` container using `volumes: - /var/lib/mysql` maps it to my local machines directory where mysql stores data to the container and because of this mapping the data should persist even if the containers are destroyed. And the `mysql` container is just a client interface into the db and can see the local directory because of `volumes_from: - data`

Attempted this answer and it did not work. [Docker-Compose Persistent Data Trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511336/docker-compose-persistent-data-trouble)

**EDIT**

Changed my `.yml` as shown below and created a the dir `./data` but now when I run `docker-compose up --build` the `mysql` container wont start throws error saying

```
  data:
    container_name: flask_data
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    command: "true"

  mysql:
    container_name: flask_mysql
    restart: always
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'test_pass' # TODO: Change this
      MYSQL_USER: 'test'
      MYSQL_PASS: 'pass'
    volumes_from:
      - data
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"


flask_mysql | mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/is_writable' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
flask_mysql | 2016-08-26T22:29:21.182144Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
flask_mysql | 2016-08-26T22:29:21.185392Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory exists and is not writable. Aborting.
```

Comment: See [my docker article](https://martin-thoma.com/docker/) and [my minimal example](https://github.com/MartinThoma/flask_mysql_dockerized)

Comment: Check user ID for files in ./data

Answer (score 366, accepted):

The data container is a superfluous workaround. [Data-volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) would do the trick for you. Alter your `docker-compose.yml` to:

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: flask_mysql
    restart: always
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'test_pass' # TODO: Change this
      MYSQL_USER: 'test'
      MYSQL_PASS: 'pass'
    volumes:
      - my-datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  my-datavolume:
```

Docker will create the volume for you in the `/var/lib/docker/volumes` folder. This volume persist as long as you are not typing `docker-compose down -v`

Comment: Starting with MySQL 5.7.6 there will (again) be [permission problems](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/69) with the `mysql` Docker image. You can instead use the `mariadb` Docker image, [which works flawlessly](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/69#issuecomment-269537249) with Docker volumes.

Comment: This solution worked for me. A couple of side notes/precisions: 
1. when you use the above configuration in docker-compose.yml and you deploy your service stack using "docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml mystack", there is no need to create the volume manually, it will be created as /var/lib/docker/volumes/mystack_my-datavolume automatically for you (notice that it prepends "mystack_" to the volume name).
2. I did not have to change permissions on my directory. Even if I have files owned by mysql:root in my container, they were created as 27:root on my Docker host without issues.

Comment: Why do you ever want to store it in `var/lib/docker/volumes` instead of having directory in your project folder like `data/mysql`?

Comment: @TheGodfather My guess would be if you don't want to deploy MySQL data to your production machine; otherwise, that's a very sound idea keeping everything together.

Comment: Can i create a folder in my root proyect and use it as database volumes?

Comment: It's simply not working on my end, the MySQL data doesn't persist on restart

Comment: For readers who use "mysql/mysql-server" image, you will need to use "MYSQL_PASSWORD" instead of "MYSQL_PASS". Otherwise the config will not work.

Comment: @TheGodfather - This doesn't answer your question completely, but I was wary about using this solution because I was worried I would inadvertently do a `docker-compose down` and lose my volume. As it turns out, you have to do `docker-compose down -v` in order to permanently lose your volume, which made me feel much better about this whole approach.

I think a better question may be, why create a directory yourself when docker can take care of it for you entirely?

Comment: @louhow I think because I feel myself more confident when *all* parts of my app and data are stored somehow together, and I have no dependencies on some volume from somewhere

Comment: `- my-datavolume:/var/lib/mysql:Z` dit it for me (workaround for permission problem )

Comment: Does anybody know why we cannot use our persistent volume folder (e.g. ./data/) but required to use the volume from docker? I tried the former on Linux and MacOS Mojave and both work fine. Only Windows failed.

Comment: I'd say that mysql volume can be kept inside the project, just git/docker ignore it to don't have the data copied on production server (it depends on the deployment process thought)

Comment: `/var/lib/docker/volumes` will be created in host or docker?

Comment: Seems like `/var/lib/docker/volumes` will exist on the Docker host for Linux hosts, not inside the container. Also, for macOS hosts, this is NOT true. (you will not find it there). Read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532483/where-is-var-lib-docker-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 84):

There are 3 ways:

**First way**

You need specify the directory to store mysql data on your **host machine**. You can then remove the data container. Your mysql data will be saved on you local filesystem.

Mysql container definition must look like this:

```
mysql:
  container_name: flask_mysql
  restart: always
  image: mysql:latest
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'test_pass' # TODO: Change this
    MYSQL_USER: 'test'
    MYSQL_PASS: 'pass'
volumes:
 - /opt/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
```

**Second way**

Would be to commit the data container before typing `docker-compose down`:

```
docker commit my_data_container
docker-compose down
```

**Third way**

Also you can use `docker-compose stop` instead of `docker-compose down` (then you don't need to commit the container)

Comment: Can't I just have `volumes: - /var/lib/mysql` because it maps `HOST:CONTAINER` and if you don't specify w/ a colon it maps the same dir?

Comment: Not. unfortunately in this case docker map this container directory to random host folder like `/var/lib/docker/volumes/ec3c543bc92f114c2c568733541e89381881e5a62996d7084e07793f86280535`

Comment: Okay I thought `volumes: - /var/lib/mysql` was equivalent to `volumes: - /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql`

Comment: your thrid way will not work because docker does not commit data from volumes to the image. see https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6999

Comment: In the first method, can two MySQL containers access and work on the same volume at once in parallel?

Comment: perhaps a 4th way, is simply using `docker compose restart` instead of `docker compose down`

Comment: the third way worked perfectly fine for me... thanks!

Comment: shouln't `volumes` and `ports` be indented to the right? inside the `mysql` key?

Answer (score 31):

first, you need to delete all old mysql data using

```
docker-compose down -v
```

after that add two lines in your docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

and

```
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

your final docker-compose.yml will looks like

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

after that use this command

```
docker-compose up -d
```

now your data will persistent and will not be deleted even after using this command

```
docker-compose down
```

extra:- but if you want to delete all data then you will use

```
docker-compose down -v
```

Answer (score 18):

You have to create a separate volume for mysql data.

So it will look like this:

```
volumes_from:
  - data
volumes:
  - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

And no, `/var/lib/mysql` is a path inside your mysql container and has nothing to do with a path on your host machine. Your host machine may even have no mysql at all. So the goal is to persist an internal folder from a mysql container.

Comment: Wouldn't this be no different than changing my `volumes` under the data container to what you put under your `volumes` and simply had `volumes_from: - data` for `mysql`? Also attempted this and thew a new error. Says dir exists but not writable and `mysql` container will not run.

Comment: Of course you have to create a local folder with a path ./mysql-data (or whatever you would put before semicolon)

Comment: See my edit. Didn't get it in before you commented. But did create local dir. Looks like there is a permission issue now.

Comment: ERROR: Service "mysql" mounts volumes from "data", which is not the name of a service or container.

Comment: I dont get it - what is `volumes_from` for?

Answer (score 17):

Adding on to the answer from @Ohmen, you could also add an `external` flag to create the data volume outside of docker compose. This way docker compose would not attempt to create it. Also you wouldn't have to worry about losing the data inside the data-volume in the event of `$ docker-compose down -v`.
The below example is from the [official page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes).

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  data:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 14):

Actually this is the path and you should mention a valid path for this to work. If your data directory is in current directory then instead of `my-data` you should mention `./my-data`, otherwise it will give you that error in `mysql` and `mariadb` also.

```
volumes:
 ./my-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Both ways are valid if used correctly. The first, without the path notations is actually a named volume, which should be initialized before it can be used. In docker-compose file, we can have a top-level volumes section to configure the mapping of a name to a specific place on the host. After that the volume can be referenced by its name solely.

Answer (score 2):

Feasible bind mount solution:

```
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /host/dir
        target: /var/lib/mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I mounted a volume named 'mysql', and this word is reserved ! Think is !

Comment: What did you try to resolve the problem?