# How to persist data in a dockerized postgres database using volumes

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

My docker compose file has three containers, web, nginx, and postgres. Postgres looks like this:

```
postgres:
  container_name: postgres
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
```

My goal is to mount a volume which corresponds to a local folder called `./database` inside the postgres container as `/var/lib/postgres`. When I start these containers and insert data into postgres, I verify that `/var/lib/postgres/data/base/` is full of the data I'm adding (in the postgres container), but in my local system, `./database` only gets a `data` folder in it, i.e. `./database/data` is created, but it's empty. Why?

Notes:

- [This suggests my above file should work.](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2971)
- [This person is using docker services which is interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175194/docker-compose-persistent-data-mysql)

#### UPDATE 1

Per Nick's suggestion, I did a `docker inspect` and found:

```
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Source": "/Users/alex/Documents/MyApp/database",
            "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
        {
            "Name": "e5bf22471215db058127109053e72e0a423d97b05a2afb4824b411322efd2c35",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/e5bf22471215db058127109053e72e0a423d97b05a2afb4824b411322efd2c35/_data",
            "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ],
```

Which makes it seem like the data is being stolen by another volume I didn't code myself. Not sure why that is. Is the postgres image creating that volume for me? If so, is there some way to use *that volume* instead of the volume I'm mounting when I restart? Otherwise, is there a good way of disabling that other volume and using my own, `./database`?

Comment: do you already run the `initdb` command line to initialize your database cluster?

Comment: Are you sure your data subdirectory is really empty? It might have special access permissions.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so fast! I'm using a flask app, so I `from app import db` and `db.create_all()` from a `docker run` after starting the containers. I don't `initdb` directly from the command line.

Comment: @YaroslavStavnichiy I don't know how else to check that than `sudo su -` and look in `./database/data`. There's nothing in there as far as I can tell.

Comment: Someone might find this useful: sample compose file persisting postgres, elastic search and media data, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56475980/5180118

Comment: Seems like if you specify a path as the first, this creates a bind_mount instead of a volume?

Answer (score 519, accepted):

Strangely enough, the solution ended up being to change

```
volumes:
  - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql
```

to

```
volumes:
  - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: Just a quick "why" for this answer (which works). Per the postgres folks, the default data directory is `/var/lib/postgresql/data` - you can read the PGDATA variable notes here: https://store.docker.com/images/022689bf-dfd8-408f-9e1c-19acac32e57b?tab=description

Comment: And add the local directory to your `.dockerignore` file, especially if you'll ever trun this into a production image.  See https://codefresh.io/blog/not-ignore-dockerignore/ for a discussion.

Comment: this does still not work for me (mac os x high sierra)

Comment: @OlliD-Metz I had to do a `docker rm my_postgres_container_1` before it worked (also High Sierra).

Comment: @rich not very helpful tip :)

Comment: If you have run the docker-compose during test without specifying the volume info, I think that you will have automatically created volumes which persist.  In my case, I had to manually delete them before the container would use the included volume info.  My solution turned out to be: docker volume rm <long volume string>

Comment: Make sure to check the logs when starting the image back up again. In my case I got an error because the local directory I was trying to mount to wasn't empty.

Comment: Also I had an issue where it wasn't realizing the directory was empty if I deleted the data directory and started it up again. Adding a trailing slash to the local folder fixed that (e.g. `- ./postgres-data/` instead of `- ./postgres-data`)

Comment: Can someone explain why it works? The first (highly upvoted) comment just states the obvious.

Comment: upvoted what is the difference between using a named volume for postgres vs a directory?

Comment: Be careful not to repeat the same silly mistake that I made: The path as defined in PGDATA is /var/lib/postgresql/data and not /var/lib/postgres/data. If you spot the difference, you are all good to go. It works for me.

Answer (score 205):

#### You can create a common **volume** for all Postgres data

```
docker volume create pgdata
```

or you can set it to the compose file

```dockerfile
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgress
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - suruse
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

It will create volume name **pgdata** and mount this volume to container's path.

#### You can inspect this volume

```
docker volume inspect pgdata
```

```
// output will be
[
    {
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/pgdata/_data",
        "Name": "pgdata",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

Comment: Commenting a bit late, but won't this clear data if I do a `docker-compose down -v`.  And what is the solution to that?

Comment: @Sid, yes, it will! Just be careful with this option.

Comment: so with docker-compose [down] the volume is no longer persisted? Does a full cleanup even of the volume?

Comment: @Sid Commenting even later, but you *can* use `docker-compose down --rmi all` *without* the `-v` option and it'll clear out "everything" *except* the volumes, i.e. containers, networks, images, etc. I do that when deploying while allowing data persistence.

Comment: What is the `suruse` for?

Comment: @IanChuTe It's a network name, you can give any name best suited to your project.

Answer (score 18):

I would avoid using a relative path. Remember that docker is a daemon/client relationship.

When you are executing the compose, it's essentially just breaking down into various docker client commands, which are then passed to the daemon. That `./database` is then relative to the *daemon*, not the client.

Now, [the docker dev team has some back and forth on this issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4830), but the bottom line is it can have some unexpected results.

In short, don't use a relative path, use an absolute path.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Sadly, I don't think it worked. I changed the line to an absolute path, and after inserting the data, the `database/data` folder is still empty =(

Comment: K. Next up is to run `docker inspect` on the container and make sure that the container is aware of the volume (just in case compose is confused or something). (note: docker inspect can have sensitive data, so don't paste it here without munging ;-)

After that, it's a matter of checking permissions (although that would usually show an error)

Comment: Aha! @Nick Burke I think you've found something. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 9):

The `postgres` image's Dockerfile contains [this line](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/dd68d91377a3631b36a23f2e4795f6189db4ba12/15/bullseye/Dockerfile#L183):

```bash
VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

When a container starts up based on this image, if nothing else is mounted there, Docker will create an *anonymous volume* and automatically mount it.  You can see this volume using commands like `docker volume ls`, and that's also the second mount in the `docker inspect` output you quote.

The main consequence of this is that your external volume mount *must* be on `/var/lib/postgresql/data` and not a parent directory.  (Also see [@AlexLenail's answer](/a/41650891).)

If you mount a host directory on `/var/lib/postgresql` instead, then:

1. Docker internally sorts the mounts, so parent directories get mounted first.
2. The host directory is mounted on `/var/lib/postgresql`.
3. Nothing is mounted on `/var/lib/postgresql/data`, so Docker creates the anonymous volume.
4. The mount point does not exist (it is in the empty bind-mounted host directory) so Docker creates it, also creating the `./database/data` directory on the host.
5. The anonymous volume is mounted on that directory, but only in the container filesystem.

The result of this is what you see, the database apparently operates correctly but its data is not necessarily persisted and you get only the empty `data` directory on the host.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to create your volume outside docker first with a `docker create -v /location --name` and then reuse it.

And by the time I used to use docker a lot, it wasn't possible to use a static docker volume with dockerfile definition so my suggestion is to try the command line (eventually with a script ) .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where postgres would create an anonymous volume in addition to the specified one.

```
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:15
    environment:
      PGUSER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/data/postgres
```

Turns out that specifying PGDATA environment variable causes that. The container would properly use the postgres_data volume, but would in addition create an empty anonymous volume.

You can find out the used volumes by using `docker inspect postgres`, here is the `Mounts` section of the output:

```
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "modular-service-layer_postgres_data",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/modular-service-layer_postgres_data/_data",
            "Destination": "/data/postgres",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "z",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        },
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "ceef11ea50a07400a798fbda75db4896f35a4a33d41c70cc68f976c187736dbd",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/ceef11ea50a07400a798fbda75db4896f35a4a33d41c70cc68f976c187736dbd/_data",
            "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ],
```

I fixed that by using the proper mount point directly without setting PGDATA:

```
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:15
    environment:
      PGUSER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```