# Docker compose not persisting data

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: myspringapp:1
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - myspringapp_postgres
  myspringapp_postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4 
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  pgdata: {}
```

myspringapp is a docker image I build previously. The problem with this is that the data is lost after doing a `docker-compose stop`.  Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/41650891/1061944

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain thanks but it's already like that.

Comment: I think you don't need to put `./` after using named volumes, in `volumes:
      - ./pgdata...`

Comment: Is your data present inside `./pgdata` on your local machine at runtime ?

Comment: Note that `./pgdata` does **not** refer to your `pgdata` volume; it refers to a directory named `pgdata` in the same directory as your `docker-compose.yml`. That should still work, of course, but the storage will not be where you expect it to be. If you want to use the `pgdata` volume, you need `pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data`.

Comment: @Daniel - The data in your postgres container - or your myspringapp container is being lost?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're defining a volume, but specifying a bind-mount to be used.

The different here, is a volume is actually it's own isolated "drive" in a sense, where a bind-mount needs to map to a specific file path on your local system.

If you check in your local `./pgdata` directory, you should find all your previous data; and to fix your issue you'll want to remove the `./` from that and **just** specify the name `pgdata` so that it uses the volume as defined. Of course, this will start you fresh again.

**compose-file.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: myspringapp:1
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - myspringapp_postgres

  myspringapp_postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4 
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  pgdata: {}
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I said in my comment, but you'll also note that I said, "this should still work". The postgres container should properly persist the data regardless of whether the storage is a docker volume or a local directory provided through a bind mount. Inside the container, they are identical (docker volumes are just bind mounts managed by docker).

Comment: that's exactly identical to what I said in my comment, but in short ;)

Comment: larsks & murtaza-khursheed-hussain Well there's not really much room for anything different :-) Although you are right; this works fine with the bind-mount, unless he was changing directories.