# Docker-compose v3 not persisting postgres database

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, persistence

I'm having difficulty persisting postgres data after a docker-compose v3 container is brought down and restarted. This seems to be a common problem, but after a lot of searching I have not been able to find a solution that works.

My question is similar to here: [How to persist data in a dockerized postgres database using volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637505/how-to-persist-data-in-a-dockerized-postgres-database-using-volumes), but the solution does not work - so please don't close. I'm going to walk through all the steps below to replicate the problem.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"  
services:  
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: zennify
      POSTGRES_USER: patientplatypus
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: SUPERSECRETPASSWORD
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  app:
    build: .
    command: ["go", "run", "main.go"]
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
volumes: 
  pgdata:
```

Here is the terminal output after I bring it up and write to my database:

```
patientplatypus:~/Documents/zennify.me/backend:08:54:03$docker-compose up
Starting backend_db_1 ... done
Starting backend_app_1 ... done
Attaching to backend_db_1, backend_app_1
db_1   | 2018-08-19 13:54:53.661 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1   | 2018-08-19 13:54:53.661 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1   | 2018-08-19 13:54:53.664 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2018-08-19 13:54:53.692 UTC [24] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-08-19 13:54:03 UTC
db_1   | 2018-08-19 13:54:53.712 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
app_1  | db init successful
app_1  | create_userinfo_table started
app_1  | create_userinfo_table finished
app_1  | inside RegisterUser in Golang
app_1  | here is the users email:
app_1  | %s pwoiioieind@gmail.com
app_1  | here is the users password:
app_1  | %s ANOTHERSECRETPASSWORD
app_1  | value of randSeq,  7NLHzuVRuTSxYZyNP6MxPqdvS0qy1L6k
app_1  | search_userinfo_table started
app_1  | value of OKtoAdd, %t true
app_1  | last inserted id = 1 //I inserted in database!
app_1  | value of initUserRet,  added
```

I can also connect to postgres in another terminal tab and verify that the database was written to correctly using `psql -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5432 -U patientplatypus zennify`. Here is the output of the `userinfo` table:

```
zennify=# TABLE userinfo
;
         email         |                           password                           |            regstring             | regbool | uid 
-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+-----
 pwoiioieind@gmail.com | $2a$14$u.mNBrITUJaVjly15BOV9.Q9XmELYRjYQbhEUi8i4vLWtOr9QnXJ6 | r33ik3Jtf0m9U3zBRelFoWyYzpQp7KzR | f       |   1
(1 row)
```

So writing to the database once works!

**HOWEVER**

Let's now do the following:

```
$docker-compose stop
backend_app_1 exited with code 2
db_1   | 2018-08-19 13:55:51.585 UTC [1] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
db_1   | 2018-08-19 13:55:51.589 UTC [1] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 30) exited with exit code 1
db_1   | 2018-08-19 13:55:51.589 UTC [25] LOG:  shutting down
db_1   | 2018-08-19 13:55:51.609 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
backend_db_1 exited with code 0
```

From reading the other threads on this topic using `docker-compose stop` as opposed to `docker-compose down` should persist the local database. However, if I again use `docker-compose up` and then, without writing a new value to the database simply query the table in postgres it is empty:

```
zennify=# TABLE userinfo;
 email | password | regstring | regbool | uid 
-------+----------+-----------+---------+-----
(0 rows)
```

I had thought that I may have been overwriting the table in my code on the initialization step, but I only have (golang snippet):

```
_, err2 := db.Exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userinfo(email varchar(40) NOT NULL, password varchar(240) NOT NULL, regString  varchar(32) NOT NULL, regBool bool NOT NULL, uid serial NOT NULL);")
```

Which should, of course, only create the table if it has not been previously created.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what is going wrong? As far as I can tell this has to be a problem with docker-compose and not my code. Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

I've looked into using version 2 of docker and following the format shown in this post ([Docker compose not persisting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47634042/docker-compose-not-persisting-data)) by using the following compose:

```
version: "2"  
services:  
  app:
    build: .
    command: ["go", "run", "main.go"]
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: zennify
      POSTGRES_USER: patientplatypus
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: SUPERSECRETPASSWORD
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
volumes:
  pgdata: {}
```

Unfortunately again I get the same problem - the data can be written but does not persist between shutdowns.

EDIT EDIT:

Just a quick note that using `docker-compose up` to instantiate the service and then relying on `docker-compose stop` and `docker-compose start` has no material affect on persistence of the data. Still does not persist across restarts.

EDIT EDIT EDIT:

Couple more things I've been finding out. If you want to properly exec into the docker container to see the value of the database you can do the following:

```
docker exec -it backend_db_1 psql -U patientplatypus -W zennify
```

where `backend_db_1` is the name of the docker container database `patientplatypus` is my username and `zennify` is the name of the database in the database container.

I've also tried, with no luck, to add a network bridge to the docker-compose file as follows:

```
version: "3"  
services:  
  db:
    build: ./db
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: patientplatypus
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: SUPERSECRET
      POSTGRES_DB: zennify
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./db/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - mynet
  app:
    build: ./
    command: bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/db/5432; do sleep 5; done; go run main.go'
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      - mynet
networks:
  mynet:
    driver: "bridge"
```

My current working theory is that, for whatever reason, my golang container is writing the postgres values it has to local storage rather than the shared volume and I don't know why. Here is my latest idea of what the golang open command should look like:

```
data.InitDB("postgres://patientplatypus:SUPERSECRET@db:5432/zennify/?sslmode=disable")
...
func InitDB(dataSourceName string) {
    db, _ := sql.Open(dataSourceName)
    ...
}
```

Again this works, but it does not persist the data.

Comment: hey, did you find soultion

Answer (score 9):

I had exactly the same problem with a postgres db and a Django app running with docker-compose.

It turns out that the Dockerfile of my app was using an entrypoint in which the following command was executed: `python manage.py flush` which clears all data in the database. As this gets executed every time the app container starts, it clears all data. It had nothing to do with docker-compose.

Comment: You sir, deserve a medal! This was driving me insane, and it was exactly the same issue. I had a `python manage.py flush --no-input` in my entrypoint. OMG

Comment: Understated answer!

Answer (score 2):

Docker named volumes are persisted with the original docker-compose you are using.

```
version: "3"  
services:  
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: zennify
      POSTGRES_USER: patientplatypus
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: SUPERSECRETPASSWORD
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
volumes: 
  pgdata:
```

How to prove it?

1) Run `docker-compose up -d` to create container and volume.

```
docker-compose up -d
Creating network "docker_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "docker_pgdata" with default driver
Pulling db (postgres:latest)...
latest: Pulling from library/postgres
be8881be8156: Already exists
bcc05f43b4de: Pull complete
....
Digest: sha256:0bbfbfdf7921a06b592e7dc24b3816e25edfe6dbdad334ed227cfd64d19bdb31
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:latest
Creating docker_db_1 ... done
```

2) Write a file on the volume location

`docker-compose exec db /bin/bash -c 'echo "File is persisted" > /var/lib/postgresql/data/file-persisted.txt'`

3) run `docker-compose down`

Notice that when you run down it removes no volumes just containers and network as per [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/). You would need to run it with `-v` to remove volumes.

`Stopping docker_db_1 ... done
Removing docker_db_1 ... done
Removing network docker_default`

Also notice your volume still exists

`docker volume ls | grep pgdata
local               docker_pgdata`

4) Run `docker-compose up -d` again to start containers and remount volumes.

5) See file is still in the volume

`docker-compose exec db /bin/bash -c 'ls -la  /var/lib/postgresql/data | grep persisted '
-rw-r--r--  1 postgres root        18 Aug 20 04:40 file-persisted.txt`

Named volumes are not host volumes. Read the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) or look up some articles to explain the difference. Also see Docker manages where it stores named volumes files and you can use different drivers but for the moment it is best you just learn the basic difference.

Comment: Thank you. This help me understand a little bit more what is going on at the mount volume when `docker-compose up` and `docker-compose down` are used. It is persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Under Environment Variables:

PGDATA
This optional environment variable can be used to define another location - like a subdirectory - for the database files. **The default is /var/lib/postgresql/data**, but if the data volume you're using is a fs mountpoint (like with GCE persistent disks), **Postgres initdb recommends a subdirectory (for example /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata ) be created to contain the data.**

more info here --> https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Comment: Oh hi Trung! Well....So I edited `volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/` to `volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata` but that doesn't seem correct and it doesn't compile. Using only `volumes: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata` compiles and runs but does not persist between restarts. I guess I'm getting confused between what the tag name should be and what the path name should be. What should the docker-compose file look like?