# Mount Postgres data to Windows host directory

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-for-windows

I want to ensure my Postgres data (using Linux based image) persist, even after my Windows host machine restart.

I tried to follow the steps [How to persist data in a dockerized postgres database using volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637505/how-to-persist-data-in-a-dockerized-postgres-database-using-volumes)

### docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

However, I'm getting error

```
waiting for server to start....FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata" has wrong ownership
HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
 stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
```

Then, I tried to follow step in https://forums.docker.com/t/trying-to-get-postgres-to-work-on-persistent-windows-mount-two-issues/12456/5

The suggested method are

```
docker volume create --name postgres_data --driver local
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  postgres:
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    external: true
```

However, I'm confused on the command `docker volume create --name postgres_data --driver local`. As, it doesn't mention the exact path of Windows host machine.

I tried

```
C:\celery-hello-world>docker volume create postgres_data
postgres_data

C:\celery-hello-world>docker volume inspect postgres_data
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2018-02-06T14:54:48Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/postgres_data/_data",
        "Name": "postgres_data",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

***May I know where is the Windows directory location, which VOLUME `postgres_data` mount to?***

Comment: it will be under `$env:ALLUSERSPROFILE\docker\volumes`

Comment: I have looked at every folders in `C:\Users`. But, can't find that docker\volumes folder.

Comment: Open powershell prompt and type `dir $env:ALLUSERSPROFILE\docker\volumes`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/yccheok/e02a87e596a30fd95fe93bafd3f6d74c - Directory volumes doesn't exists.

Comment: Did you modify your daemon.json configuration in docker by adding `graph` or `data-root`?

Comment: Nope. I didn't modify anything. I just use the default docker windows installer.

Comment: Never mind I just realized you are using UNIX containers. I'm not sure how those are presented on Windows filesystem since container actually run in VM on Windows

Comment: Sorry. I should mentioned clearly in my question.

Comment: have you tried locating the volume using a Bash shell? IIRC, WSL isolates the *nix file system from the Windows FS.

Answer (score 0):

Today i was asking myself the same question but i have figured it out.

First to note is that inside postgres container the path is:

```
 /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Now the path you tried to track down is another path:

> C:\celery-hello-world>docker volume inspect postgres_data [
>       {
>           "CreatedAt": "2018-02-06T14:54:48Z",
>           "Driver": "local",
>           "Labels": {},
>           "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/postgres_data/_data",
>           "Name": "postgres_data",
>           "Options": {},
>           "Scope": "local"
>       } ]

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes/postgres_data/_data
```

I am also using `Docker for windows` and `Unix` containers.

As you can check normally you will not see this docker machine:

```
docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS
```

But there's a trick to access it regarding `Unix` containers:

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1
```

> Just run this from your CLI and it'll drop you in a container with
>   full permissions on the Moby VM. Only works for Moby Linux VM (doesn't
>   work for Windows Containers). Note this also works on Docker for Mac.

Reference: https://www.bretfisher.com/getting-a-shell-in-the-docker-for-windows-vm/

From there you can navigate to this folder (note that i named my volume `postgresql-volume`):

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes/postgresql-volume/_data    ls
    PG_VERSION            pg_dynshmem           pg_notify             pg_stat_tmp           postgresql.auto.conf
    base                  pg_hba.conf           pg_replslot           pg_subtrans           postgresql.conf
    global                pg_ident.conf         pg_serial             pg_tblspc             postmaster.opts
    pg_clog               pg_logical            pg_snapshots          pg_twophase           postmaster.pid
    pg_commit_ts          pg_multixact          pg_stat               pg_xlog
```

So to be clear it's inside of the VM provided by `Docker for Windows` in the directory above.

`Docker for windows` needs `Hyper-V` enabled for virtualization.

You can also find image location in `Docker for windows` go to `Settings->Advanced`->`Disk image location` in my case it's:

```
"C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\vm-data\DockerDesktop.vhdx"
```

Also note that the same could be found in `Hyper-V Manager`.