# Docker container shuts down giving 'data directory has wrong ownership' error when executed in windows 10

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I have my docker installed in Windows. I am trying to install [this](https://github.com/Attendize/Attendize) application. It has given me the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-nginx
    ports:
    - "8085:80"
    networks:
      - attendizenet
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/share/nginx/html/attendize
    depends_on:
      - php
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-php
    depends_on:
      - db
      - maildev
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/share/nginx/html/attendize
    networks: 
      - attendizenet
  php-worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-php
    depends_on:
      - db
      - maildev
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/share/nginx/html/attendize
    command: php artisan queue:work --daemon
    networks:
      - attendizenet
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=attendize
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=attendize
      - POSTGRES_DB=attendize
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
    - attendizenet
  maildev:
    image: djfarrelly/maildev
    ports:
      - "1080:80"
    networks:
      - attendizenet
  redis:
    image: redis
    networks:
      - attendizenet

networks:
  attendizenet:
    driver: bridge
```

All the installation goes well, but the PostgreSQL container stops after starting for a moment giving following error.

```
2018-03-07 08:24:47.927 UTC [1] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership
2018-03-07 08:24:47.927 UTC [1] HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory
```

A simple PostgreSQL container from Docker Hub works smoothly, but the error occurs when we try to attach a volume to the container.

I am new to docker, so please ignore usage of terms wrongly.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to occur anymore on [Docker with WSL2 backend](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is a documented problem with the Postgres Docker image on Windows [[1](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/435)][[2](https://forums.docker.com/t/data-directory-var-lib-postgresql-data-pgdata-has-wrong-ownership/17963)][[3](https://forums.docker.com/t/trying-to-get-postgres-to-work-on-persistent-windows-mount-two-issues/12456)][[4](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)]. Currently, there doesn't appear to be a way to correctly mount Windows directories as volumes. You could instead use a persistent Docker volume, for example:

```
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=attendize
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=attendize
      - POSTGRES_DB=attendize
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
    - attendizenet

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Other things that didn't work:

- Set PGDATA to a subdirectory (See [PGDATA Setting](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres))

```
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/mnt
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

- Use a Bind Mount (docker-compose 3.2)

```
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./pgdata
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

- Running as POSTGRES_USER=root

More Information:

GitHub

- [data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/435)

Docker Forums

- [postgresql-data-pgdata-has-wrong-ownership](https://forums.docker.com/t/data-directory-var-lib-postgresql-data-pgdata-has-wrong-ownership/17963)
- [postgres-to-work-on-persistent-windows-mount](https://forums.docker.com/t/trying-to-get-postgres-to-work-on-persistent-windows-mount-two-issues/12456)

Comment: Using a named volume is the right solution. I prefer mounted volumes as it's easier for me but this will suffice. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Please refer reinierkors' answer from [here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/435). The answer is as follows copied as is from the link here for reader's convenience and works for me

I solved this by mapping my local volume one directory below the one Postgres needs:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Comment: Mounting parent directory has an issue with saving data.. see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76217607/2238873

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue after downgrading my Docker from `WSL 2` to `WSL 1` and what [Thomas Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695742/thomas-taylor)'s pertaining, I solved the issue by using [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg12
    ...
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ...


volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Answer (score 1):

Map the local volume (e.g. C:\docker\pgdata) to one level (one directory) above what PostgreSQL needs. You can also do it from command line when starting the docker:

```
docker run -itd -e POSTGRES_USER=pguser -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pgpasswd \
  -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata -p 5432:5432 \
  -v c:\docker\pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql --name postgresql postgres
```

Comment: This worked for me in docker-compose as well. Mount lib/postgresql instead of lib/postgresql/data. volumes:- ./docker/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql

Comment: Mounting parent directory has issue with saving data.. see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76217607/2238873

Answer (score 1):

I met this issue when re-installed docker and used wsl-1 backend.

solution: switch docker to wsl-2 backend.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Even i had the problem i had to copy the data dir at regular intervals.

```
 docker cp <container-name>:/var/lib/postgresql/data C:/docker/volumes/postgres
```

Answer (score -7):

Owner for the data folder in postgres inside the container is Postgres user. Your current user may not have access privilege in the mounted folder. You need to give all permissions according to the requirements by given command below :

```
chmod 777 ./docker/pgdata
```

If this command is not helping to resolve this issue please refer the following link to do the user mapping from inside the container to outside the container.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/#prerequisites

Comment: ./docker/pgdata folder in in windows, having all executable rights.