# How to attach a PostgreSQL volume to a Docker image generated with SBT native packager?

Tags: scala, docker, playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I would like to be able to deploy my app in a `pre-prod` environment for integration testing using a Docker volume that will expose an instance of PostgreSQL. I'm using Scala v2.12.8 and Play v2.7.

Looking at the [environment settings](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html#environment-settings) of the SBT native packager it seems possible to define `dockerExposedVolumes` in order to attach a DB.

Using a normal Docker compose file I would do something like that:

```
   version: "3"
   services:
     db:
       image: postgres
       environment:
         - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
         - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgress
         - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
       ports:
         - "5433:5432"
       volumes:
         - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
       networks:
         - suruse
   volumes: 
     pgdata:
```

This configuration has been taken from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45606440/1977778).

I tried searching for config examples but I didn't find anything useful so far. Now I'm wondering **how I should define a new docker volume and then expose it to the Docker image created by SBT exactly?**

---

### THE WORKING SOLUTION

The final version. I've fully tested it and it works exposing the DB on the TCP port 5433.

```
# https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/postgres/
version: "3"
services:
  app-pgsql:
    image: postgres:9.6
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=yourPasswordHere
      - POSTGRES_DB=yourDatabaseNameHere
      - POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS="--encoding=UTF8"
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes: 
  pgdata:
    driver: local
```

Launch the docker compose using `sbt dockerComposeUp -useStaticPorts` and then check if the containers have been actually exposed using `docker ps -a`. Also, check the log files using the command provided by `dockerComposeUp` or `dockerComposeInstances`.

Comment: Why not use postgres in its own docker image?

Comment: I would like to create and attach a DB image using `sbt docker:publishLocal`. Is that doable? Otherwise, could you please point me in the right direction? Should I define a docker compose file with a PostgreSQL image in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a **sbt Plugin** that helps you to achieve this:

**[sbt-docker-compose](https://github.com/Tapad/sbt-docker-compose)**

With that you can add your database to a docker compose file and you can run everything within sbt.

This is a Docker standard. Here is an explaination how to do it for Postgres:

```
[run_postgresql_docker_compose][2]
```

The `docker-compose.yml` from that example:

```
version: '3'
services:
mydb:
image: postgres
volumes:
- db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
ports:
         - 5432:5432/tc

volumes:
db-data:
driver: local
```

As this is a standard way of Docker you will find more examples.

Comment: I suppose I might start from [this example](https://github.com/Tapad/sbt-docker-compose/tree/master/examples/basic-native-packager). Could you please add an example of what this compose file should look like?

Comment: see my adjusted example

Comment: apparently the container keeps restarting or stops immediately after the dockerComposeUp. Do you know why that happens?

Comment: have you checked the logs? the Docker-Log of postres docker image

Comment: Checking the logs I found that `- POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS="--encoding=UTF8 --locale=en_US.UTF8"` is not a valid server encoding name. Changing it to just `encoding=UTF8` seems to have fixed the issue. Thank you for your support. I accepted your response.