# Facing issue in mounting portgresql persistance volume in kubernetes locally

Tags: kubernetes, postgresql-9.3, persistent-volumes

I am trying to mount postgrsql persitance volume in kubernetes locally with static provisioning.
Here is my yaml file i created pv , pvc and pod

```
 apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolume
    metadata:
      name: task-pv-volume
      namespace: manhattan
      labels:
        type: local
    spec:
      storageClassName: manual
      capacity:
        storage: 100Mi
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      hostPath:
        path: "/mnt/data"
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      name: task-pv-claim
      namespace: manhattan
    spec:
      storageClassName: manual
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 80Mi
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: dbr-postgres
 namespace: manhattan
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: task-pv-claim
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: postgresql:2.0.1
      tty: true
      volumeMounts:
        -  mountPath: "/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data"
           name: task-pv-storage
           subPath: data
           readOnly: false
  nodeSelector:
     kubernetes.io/hostname: k8s-master
```

My volume lies in the /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data  but my pod fails and i don't want to change the location of mountPath to   /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/backup

can you please suggest any overwrite option in yaml file

I don't want to create the folder with new name here .

[image]

If i changed the mountPath to   /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/backup the pod starts running but i dont want that i want the data to writtend in  the same directory /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data

Comment: Add the backup folder but change subPath from data to backup.

Comment: Even better, don't use subpath. You don't need it.

Comment: But psql data directory reads only inside data directory but it doesn't allow me to create mountPoint with the name data

Comment: Please provide information what image are you using? Is this your custom build or the official one?

Comment: Custom one . And i loaded my data in the dockerfile itself

Comment: I also tried with the official  of Postgres image but same issue

Comment: Please provide information what  exactly image are you using?

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Comment: a database (especially a relational one) in k8s cluster already sounds wrong to me.

Answer (score 1):

As per official documentation for postgres:9.4 from dockerhub:

**1**. Please Note:

> Warning: the Docker specific variables will only have an effect if you start the container with a data directory that is empty; any pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup.

**2**. `PGDATA` environment variable:

> This optional variable can be used to define another location - like a subdirectory - for the database files. The default is /var/lib/postgresql/data, but if the data volume you're using is a filesystem mountpoint (like with GCE persistent disks), Postgres initdb recommends a subdirectory (for example /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata ) be created to contain the data.

As workaround please refer to:

- the official docs while working with [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/4b652bf95baee9cd7ef31300a4938ad72d09ad88/9.4/alpine/Dockerfile)
- helm charts for stable [postgresql](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql)

You can also change the image to the specific one [using helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql#deploy-chart-using-docker-official-postgresql-image):

> From chart version 4.0.0, it is possible to use this chart with the Docker Official PostgreSQL image. Besides specifying the new Docker repository and tag, it is important to modify the PostgreSQL data directory and volume mount point. Basically, the PostgreSQL data dir cannot be the mount point directly, it has to be a subdirectory.

```
helm install --name postgres \
             --set image.repository=postgres \
             --set image.tag=10.6 \
             --set postgresqlDataDir=/data/pgdata \
             --set persistence.mountPath=/data/ \
             stable/postgresql
```

You can template this helm chart and customizing. From another point of view the main problem is that you have initialized your database  - as you mentioned under /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/backup so please verify your docker file and your docker-entrypoint.sh to figure out where is the problem.

Please let me know if this helped.

Comment: But during configuration i intiate postgres db service postgresql-9.3 initdb it creates my all data directory and i wants to mount that directory into  the volume

Comment: Do I need any additional configuration in my yaml file or is there any permission issue

Comment: You can find more information in postgresql specific posts, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637505/how-to-persist-data-in-a-dockerized-postgres-database-using-volumes). In docker documentation [Where to Store Data](https://hub.docker.com/_/022689bf-dfd8-408f-9e1c-19acac32e57b) the recomended way is to mount your data in `/var/lib/postgresql/data`. Please use `kubectl logs your container` to see any permissiosn issues. In addition please use init container in order to prepare permissions securitycontext and volume + env varaibles used by postgresql server binary.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the issue its arises because my data directory is not empty initially.I need to run **postgresql init db** during **ENTRYPOINT** OR **CMD** at run time

It is must in kubernetes volume to have empty mountPath but it works fine if you are using docker volume for mounting