# Docker volume associated to postgres image empty and not persistent

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a docker-compose file to build a web server with django and a postgres database. It basically looks like that :

```
version: '3'

services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/server/Dockerfile
    image: backend
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

  postgres:
    image: kartoza/postgis:11.0-2.5
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "gis,backend"
      POSTGRES_PORT: "5432"
      POSTGRES_USER: "user"
      POSTGRES_PASS: "pass"
      POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_EXTENSIONS: "postgis,postgis_topology"
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"

volumes:
  pg_data:
```

I'm using a volume to make my data persistent
I managed to run my containers and add data to the database. A volume has successfully been created : `docker volume ls`

```
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               server_pg_data
```

But this volume is empty as the output of `docker system df -v` shows:

```
Local Volumes space usage:

VOLUME NAME                                                        LINKS               SIZE
server_pg_data                                                     1                   0B
```

Also, if I want or need to build the containers once again using `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up`, data has been purged from my database. Yet, I thought that volumes were used to make data persistent on disk…

I must be missing something in the way I'm using docker and volumes but I don't get what:

- why does my volume appears empty while there is some data in my postgres container ?
- why does my volume does not persist after doing `docker-compose down` ?

This thread ([How to persist data in a dockerized postgres database using volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637505/how-to-persist-data-in-a-dockerized-postgres-database-using-volumes)) looked similar but the solution does not seem to apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `kartoza/postgis` image](https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/postgis) isn't configured the same way as the standard `postgres` image.  Its documentation notes (under "Cluster Initializations"):

> By default, `DATADIR` will point to `/var/lib/postgresql/{major-version}`. You can instead mount the parent location like this: `-v data-volume:/var/lib/postgresql`

If you look at the Dockerfile in GitHub, you will also see [that parent directory named as a `VOLUME`](https://github.com/kartoza/docker-postgis/blob/develop/Dockerfile#L69), which has some interesting semantics here.

With the setting you show, the actual data will be stored in `/var/lib/postgresql/11.0`; you're mounting the named volume on a different directory, `/var/lib/postgresql/data`, which is why it stays empty.  Changing the volume mount to just `/var/lib/postgresql` should address this:

```yaml
volumes:
  - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql:rw # not .../data
```

Comment: in the documentation, that part quoted is followed by: `-v data-volume:/opt/postgres/data \
-e DATADIR:/opt/postgres/data \ ` -> that is confusing, maybe DATADIR env isn't actually being checked for where to store data?

Comment: Thanks, just mounting /var/lib/postgresql on a persistent volume did the job, my dockerised postgresql+postgis is persistent now.