# postgres database doesn't exist in docker container

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

**My docker-compose.yml is:**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123
      POSTGRES_DB: "haircut_studio"
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
    volumes:
      - ./log-directory:/var/lib/postgresql
  app:
    build: ../
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - DATASOURCE_HOST=db
      - DATASOURCE_PORT=5432
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**Dockerfile is:**

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
COPY / /spd
WORKDIR /spd
RUN chmod +x gradlew
RUN ./gradlew :bootJar
WORKDIR /spd/build/libs
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java","-jar", "haircutStudio-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#logging.level.root=debug

server.port=8080
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher

datasource.username=postgres
datasource.password=123
datasource.host=localhost
datasource.port=5432
datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${datasource.host}:${datasource.port}/haircut_studio
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate = true
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=ERROR
```

**TestDbConfig.java**

```
package com.spdu.haircutstudio.configuration;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class DbConfig {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource getDataSource(
            @Value("${datasource.password}") String password,
            @Value("${datasource.username}") String username,
            @Value("${datasource.url}") String jdbcUrl
    ) {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);

        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public Flyway flyway(DataSource dataSource) {
        final Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .locations("classpath:db")
                .outOfOrder(true)
                .load();
        flyway.migrate();
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I built my app image everything was ok, then I should start my db image and app image. I start db with `docker-compose up db` and I got: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "haircut_studio" does not exist`. Is something wrong with my DbConfig? If I start my app locally, not in Docker container my app successfully connects to DB and I can do everything, that I want. How I can fix this error?

Here is GitLab repo: https://gitlab.com/staaankey/java/-/tree/reservation-feature

Comment: Can you log and check your datasource url?

Comment: The Postgres container only creates the POSTGRES_DB database if no database already exists in /var/lib/postgresql. So make sure `./log-directory` is empty on the host before you start the containers.

Comment: @HansKilian .local/log-directory/data is empty before I start

Comment: @tbjorch How i can do this? I restarted my container and got this: ```PS C:\Users\hp-laptop-dmytro\IdeaProjects\java\.local> docker-compose up app
Starting local_db_1 ... done
Starting local_app_1 ... done``` But when my app image is trying to connect to DB in logs of my app same error: ```FATAL: database "haircut_studio" does not exist```

Comment: @tbjorch I provided a link to the GitLab repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default data directory is /var/lib/postgresql/data.
You need to adjust your volume:

```
volumes:
  - ./log-directory:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41650891/1563297)