# MySQL-workbench and Docker Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)

Tags: docker, mysql-workbench

Om Mac I'm using docker for my local web and I want to access mysql with MySQL-workbench but after I did install MySQL-workbench and try to connect to database I get this error message

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
```

[image: img]

I tried to find solution for docker but I didn't find any.

docker inspect pkbook_mysql_1

```
"NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "cb984bedd303958298621c1571482c7c06a2a326df021902c15a7955b8c26b2c",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "3306/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/cb984bedd303",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "publiquip_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "mysql",
                        "ee6b2dd46fb8"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "8809726a588595aea20989df3608ae6646f2e64aa928974469df34b52febe7a4",
                    "EndpointID": "f41cf7f7e42f4921393e13c7db9ce046c784c159ad0ff3c74d45ed788323d4b1",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.20.0.4",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:04",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
```

docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
e34b4dbad1e3        pkbook_joomla    "/entrypoint.sh apac…"   4 days ago          Up 5 hours          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   pkbook_joomla_1
ee6b2dd46fb8        mysql:5.6           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 days ago          Up 5 hours          3306/tcp             pkbook_mysql_1
0ccd811b7955        pkbook_gulp      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 days ago          Up 5 hours                               pkbook_gulp_1
```

Comment: Try using 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: please add the docker command you use to run mysql

Comment: mysql -u pkbook -ppkbook pkbook<pkbook.sql; the web is working perfect

Comment: @dfundako : same problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to publish the 3306 port with the -p opt option.

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -p 3306:3306 mysql
```

Comment: I typed : docker run -p 3306:3306 mysql on docker but i get 
Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user pkbook

Comment: From where are you failing to connect ? Your host machine or another container ?

Comment: Try to connect with root. The password is set by an env variable when mysql image is run like this : docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -p 3306:3306 mysql

Comment: I did trying to connecting using root that too not working

Comment: Can you run this command please ? sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P

Comment: `COMMAND    PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.docke  446 Lotfi    7u  IPv4 0x1816959b5bbf7377      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:49218 (LISTEN)
com.docke  450 Lotfi   15u  IPv6 0x1816959b5bc04437      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
Code\x20H 1232 Lotfi   41u  IPv4 0x1816959b5b8bf377      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:10288 (LISTEN)`

Comment: You don't seem to have a Mysql listening to 3306, please make sure you publish the 3306 port from docker as mentionned in my answer.

Comment: you command give this message: `error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified 
  You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD`

Comment: Well yes you have the solution in one of the comments I gave. I'll edit the answer for more clarity.

Comment: I used your code but seems nothing work that what I did `docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pkbook -p 3306:3306 mysql`

Comment: Give us the lsof and the connection result now.

Comment: `Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user pkbook` I did on docker `I did docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pkbook -p 3306:3306 mysql`

Comment: Connect as root, not pkbook. Please give a bit more attention to answers you get, I'm kind of losing patience. Thanks.

Comment: `Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root`

Comment: I used your code exact except I changed the password `docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pkbook -p 3306:3306 mysql`

Comment: Is the error code still (61) ? Does the lsof command shows your mysql now ?

Comment: I get this error `Access denied for user 'pkbook'@'172.17.0.1' (using password: YES)` My database is pkbook the user is pkbook and password is pkbook why I use root

Comment: You just run a mysql docker image, it does not have pkbook user. Connect as root and then create the user(s) you need. The error you quoted is still related to this non-existent pkbook user. Run my command, connect as root, if you have trouble post the entire error message and the lsof command result.

Comment: it access but my database pkbook isn't there for me I was trying to open my database pkbook

Comment: Well of course there is not your database, nor your pkbook user, you just created a new container, hence a new mysql instance. This is now a different question, your connection problem is resolved, you can accept my answer. About persisting data with a mysql container, you'll need to mount a volume, see this [post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175194/docker-compose-persistent-data-mysql) for instance.

Comment: I did Accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of host 127.0.0.1 try to type container name and port.
If it doesn't work.

In terminal type `docker ps`. (If You didn't gave the name during container creation, docker will name it by random name). If container is running You should see it on the list.

Then check IP and PORT:

`docker inspect [CONTAINER-NAME]`

and find under:

"NetworkSettings":

```
                "3306/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "33082"
                    }
                ],
                "33060/tcp": null
            },
```

So, in this situation it's 0.0.0.0:33082

Comment: I edit my question and posted result from docker inspect pkbook_mysql_1

Comment: Looks like You're missing publishing the ports. Pretty much what Thomas Martin said but he called it exposing the ports. Which is not the same. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/what-is-the-difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker 
If this won't help You please write how You start the container? By docker commands or docker-compose?

Answer (score -2):

You need to set the allow login from any ip with **MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%**

Full docker command line as follows:

```
>docker run --name mysql-server -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345 -p 3306:3306 -d mysql/mysql-server
```

> --name means that it's container name
>
> -d means that it's mysql docker image

When docker status is  **Up 3 minutes (healthy)** you can easy connect to DB via mysql Workbench