# How can I set persistent data in docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

New to Docker, and moving on to docker compose.  In the past I would start up a container with: `docker run -v /localFolder:/containerFolder containerName`

I am trying to do the same in a docker-compose.yml, or even in Dockerfile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker-Compose persistent data MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175194/docker-compose-persistent-data-mysql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`volumes`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes)

```
volumes: 

# Just specify a path and let the Engine create a volume
 - /var/lib/mysql 

# Specify an absolute path mapping
 - /opt/data:/var/lib/mysql 

# Path on the host, relative to the Compose file
 - ./cache:/tmp/cache 

# User-relative path
 - ~/configs:/etc/configs/:ro 

# Named volume
 - datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
```

See also detailed post: [Use volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to persist the data in volume to the instance

```
services:
  redis:
    volumes:
      - '_data:/var/lib/data'

volumes:
  _data:
    driver: local
```