# How do I automate backing up MYSQL database container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I have a MYSQL database container running on a centos server. How do I automate backing up the database outside the container?

Comment: just use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to persist your database out side containers. also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175194/docker-compose-persistent-data-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments, make sure you use volumes for data folder.

for backing up:

1. create a bash script on the host machine and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
docker exec <container name> /usr/bin/mysqldump -u <putdatabaseusername here> -p<PutyourpasswordHere> --all-databases > /<path to desired backup location>/$DATE.sql
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
    find /<path to desired backup location>/ -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \;
fi
```

change the following:

`<container name>` to actual db container name

`<putdatabaseusername here>` to db user

`<PutyourpasswordHere>` to the db password

create a directory for backup files and replace `/<path to desired backup location>/` to the actual path

2. create a cronjob on host machine that executes the script in desired time/period

note that this script will retain backups for 10 days, change the number to reflect your needs.

**Important note:** this script is storing the password in the file, use a secure way in production