# Apache Superset MySQL Initialization Error: '--initialize' specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting."

Tags: sql, mysql, docker

I am currently in the process of migrating the metadata database of my Apache Superset instance from **PostgreSQL to MySQL**, and I am facing challenges in defining the appropriate volume for MySQL data in the context of **Google Cloud SQL**.

I have updated the Docker Compose configuration to use the MySQL image, and here's a snippet of the Docker Compose file related to the MySQL service in the **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
db:
env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
image: mysql:5.7
container_name: superset_db
restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  - db_home:/var/lib/mysql/data
```

However, I am encountering the following **error** in the logs:

```
 2023-09-27T05:52:30.050470Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db_1                    | 2023-09-27T05:52:30.058556Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
db_1                    | 2023-09-27T05:52:30.059190Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
db_1                    | 
superset_db exited with code 1
```

Research indicates that the issue might be related to the volume not being properly defined. Given that I am using Google Cloud SQL as the database, I am unsure about where to find the correct path for the MySQL volume. I've tried specifying db_home and db_data in various locations, but it seems like a brute-force approach. I am adding this to the **superset_config.py** file:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://{user_name}:{password}@{hostname}/superset'
#here superset is my database
```

Could someone guide me on the correct volume configuration for MySQL in this context, especially when using Google Cloud SQL as the backend database?

Comment: @nico-haase I am trying to learn. Why is this question closed while that https://stackoverflow.com/q/39175194/22257868 one is OK? The only difference of this question here is the additional context `google-cloud` and `Apache Superset`.

Comment: Feel free to flag the other posting as off topic. There are not that much users who flag posts such that all postings could be handled

Comment: Alright, but I would not dare to flag a question from over 7 years ago which created value to this site. I am just trying to get the pattern here. Thank your your reply though.

Comment: Hi
@NicoHaase
I'm a bit puzzled about why this question got closed. I tried tweaking the style, but to me, it seems like a programming problem, not a discussion. Any tips on how I can edit it to get it reopened?

Comment: I've identified the issue. When integrating with Google Cloud Run, there's no need to mention the db in the docker-compose file. It can communicate directly with the Google Cloud server. Simply comment out the entire db section, and it should work seamlessly.
And also change the Database host to the private IP of Cloud SQL.

Comment: Feel free to share how this is related to programming. As far as I see, you haven't shared any code so far. I would assume this is an issue of configuring existing software?

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted the volume like this, hope it helps

```
volumes:
    - ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
```